# Flutter Crashes on Samsung S9 devices only

Tags: android, flutter

[image: Flutter Crash]

Not sure what is causing this...
I have disabled hardware acceleration as suggested on other threads.

```
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Side note: I was unable to get a crash when testing on the remote test lab. Perhaps the ones available there are running on a different chip set than the devices that are crashing.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? The same is happening with my S9 device/

Comment: I was never able to figure it out. I think (although not certain) that the issue is mostly gone after multiple updates to the app / flutter version, but I'm not sure which component was responsible.